# Hard disk file system is shown as Raw file system; how can I access it?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

My Portable harddisk was working fine. I once accessed it from a linux terminal. Later when I tried to use it in window it said `You need to format it before you can access`

In Ubuntu also when I plug it, it does not appear.

I tried running `chkdisk` but Windows says Raw file system could not be processed.

Is there any way I can get back the disk data?

Recovery software does not preserve folder when it recovers data. Also When I tried it it says "1 days remaining to process" nearly 350GB data.

Comment: Please do not cross post. Choose one SE site that the question fits best and post it there. If you later decide it should be asked elsewhere, flag a question and a moderator will move it.

Comment: @gronostaj: I got suggestion that this question suits better here, so asked again. Aplogize

Comment: What do you mean "Recovery software does not preserve folder when it recovers data." And what recovery software?

Comment: @JanDoggen: I mean when I use `Recuva` then it shows all recovered files in one directory. It does not recover folder by folder. In the same structure as the data is in hard drive

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu/Linux available? What it reports when you do `dmesg | tail` after plugging the drive?

Comment: @Braiam: I needed to format linux, I need to reinstall and check it!